# add_action to wp_head is added, but not called

Tags: actions, wp-head

I'm using the [CiviCRM](http://civicrm.org) plugin for WordPress, and in the plugin's main file, `civicrm.php`, it calls `add_action()` to add a function to `wp_head()` in order to merge CiviCRM's header with my theme's header:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'wp_head' ) );
```

The actual function within civicrm.php is found below:

```
public function wp_head() {
  echo "calling wp_head"; //added by me to test if the code gets called
  // CRM-11823 - If Civi bootstrapped, then merge its HTML header with the CMS's header
  global $civicrm_root;
  if ( empty( $civicrm_root ) ) {
    return;
  }

  $region = CRM_Core_Region::instance('html-header', FALSE);
  if ( $region ) {
    echo '<!-- CiviCRM html header -->';
    echo $region->render( '' );
  }

}
```

I have confirmed that the code gets called when I switch to the twentyfifteen theme, but on my custom theme (which is based on an old version of [Roots](http://roots.io)), this code does not get called. I have also confirmed that my custom theme is actually calling the main WordPress `wp_head()` function.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong in my custom theme that would cause this custom `wp_head` hook to not get called or otherwise error out in some way?

Comment: Can you verify that `wp_head()` is being called in your theme's header?

Comment: Have you tried adding your own hook to `wp_head` to see if that works?

Comment: Yes - I made sure that the main `wp_head() ` function is actually being called in my theme's header. I put an echo in another function and it's being printed. The CiviCRM function, however, is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue:

When CiviCRM was applying the template in `civicrm.basepage.php`, `$page_template` was coming back as `page.php`, but my base template was actually named `base.php`.

I added the following code in my theme's initialization and it resolved the issue:

```
add_filter( 'civicrm_basepage_template', 'psca_civicrm_basepage_template' );
function psca_civicrm_basepage_template( $template ) {
  return 'base.php';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can we think litter bit different way:

```
add_action('wp_head','new_wp_head');
function new_wp_head() {
  echo "calling wp_head"; 
  global $civicrm_root;
  if ( empty( $civicrm_root ) ) {
    return;
  }
  $region = CRM_Core_Region::instance('html-header', FALSE);
  if ( $region ) {
    echo '<!-- CiviCRM html header -->';
    echo $region->render( '' );
  }
}
```

Make sure in which file you put this and it's hook with your theme or plugins.